# Move immediate 8-bit value into RSI, RDI, RSP or RBP

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I took a look at the opcodes generated by these assembly codes :

```
xor rsi, rsi
mov sil, 0xFF
```

and

```
mov rsi, 0xFF
```

The first code turns into `48 31 F6 40 B6 FF` and the second into `48 C7 C6 FF 00 00 00`.

1. Is code with more instructions slower?
2. Is what matters more the size taken up by the opcodes?
3. Which code produces the highest performance?

**EDIT**: in the comments I saw `mov esi, 0xFF` is a better solution and in a way it is a good answer. I am not sure about this question but what if we look only at the codes I wrote?

Comment: The best solution for this one is `mov esi, 0xff` which encodes to `be ff 00 00 00`.  Both code size and number of instructions matter, but number of instructions is usually more important for performance.  Beware though, some instructions are slower than others and can be replaced by sequences that perform better.

Comment: @fuz Thank you. Do you have examples of such sequences?

Comment: Note that 32 bit operations zero extend to 64 so you can use `esi`.

Comment: @zonn For example, `xadd eax, ecx` is slower than `mov ebx, eax; add eax, ecx; mov ecx, ebx` on most microarchitectures.

Comment: If you were optimizing for code size instead of performance, you'd use `push 0xff` / `pop rsi` (3 bytes total).  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132985) But if you already had a zeroed register, like RDI for example, `lea esi, [rdi + 0xff]` (or actually any other known value within -128..+127 of the value you want, preferably in a register that isn't the end of a long dependency chain (e.g. a loop counter that reached zero after a loop isn't ideal on out-of-order exec CPUs.)

Comment: See https://agner.org/optimize/ and [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391)

Comment: @PeterCordes The `lea` you suggest with a `0xFF` displacement is not actually in the signed disp8 range.

Comment: @ecm: oops!  You're right, I even said later in my comment that it has to be within signed 8-bit range, not unsigned.  At least it's relevant for the general case of the title question about some 8-bit values, or maybe you have a value between `0x80` and `0x17F` in another register